# Vlc on Ubuntu live usb

Tags: live-usb, vlc

I created Ubuntu live usb stick and I wanted install vlc on it.

I downloaded the package but it didn't install.

I tried the `sudo apt-get` method, but it didn't work.

Is there any way how to install vlc on Ubuntu live without installing it on computer?

Comment: Did you try a simple `sudo apt-get install vlc` in a terminal? If that doesn't work, what is the error message?

Comment: could not find packedge vlc

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, ***vlc*** is in the repository **universe**. If it is not available, you must activate that repository. You can do it with the following commands (or with some GUI tool, for example ***synaptic***).

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

then it should work to install vlc with

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer! On 18.04, without the universe repos enven the ppa doesn't work (E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Note that to install a program in live mode and that changes when you shut down not miss is to allocate space for persistence. I have understood that the only live usb creator that allows that is UNetbootin.
Try also enabled all repositories in software origins

Comment: i used this tool many times and i put the space about 1000 MB and still didn't work

Comment: try this  sudo snap install vlc  **bold**

Comment: how can i install it?

Comment: ¿Ubuntu version?

Comment: no the vlc program